# Pass the Model class object to Kendo Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

My application is MVC 5, I am using Kendo ui MVC diagram.  I have developed editor template, works well except I can't get value from the model. I have tried:

```
@using WebUI.Models
@model WebUI.Models.OrgChartShape

<h2> @Model.FirstName</h2>
```

and

```
@{
    string data = Model.FirstName;
}
<h2> @data</h2>
```

I also tried:

```
@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model.FirstName,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented))
```

It returns null.  I can get the value using:

```
 @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "k-textbox", data_bind = "value:FirstName" }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that kendo custom templates are kendo MVVM.  I used , this works.